# Footnotes: Large space between text and number in justified text

Tags: spacing, footnotes

I have inserted a footnote in a justified column. However, the space between the text and superscript is huge. How do I keep the superscript number next to the text?
[image]

Comment: Can you show the input code? There should be no space in front of `\footnote`

Comment: Nicest spacing in my eyes: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fnpct}
\begin{document}
in Figure~7 is not uniform\footnote{footnote text}. Within-
\end{document}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `\footnote` command doesn't remove spaces before it. So, in general, it should be immediately after the word that should bear the footnote mark, with no intervening spaces. So

```
of the means as reported in Figure~\ref{whatever} is not
uniform.\footnote{The text of the footnote.} Within
```

A space like in

```
uniform. \footnote{The text of the footnote.}
```

will produce what you see in the picture.